# iptables or firewalld to close all ports except ssh?

Tags: iptables, firewall

I've the following question: How can I close all ports except port 22.
nmap shows me all used ports:

```
nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-02-20 20:06 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000050s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.08 seconds
```

also `netstate` displays open connections:

```
sudo netstat -tulpen | grep -v '127.0.0.1'  | grep -v '::1:'
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          160309215   286/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          160309218   286/sshd
```

but these 999 are not really closed they are not in use.

`iptables -L`  gives:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

so every port is open now.

Since this is an external server I have to keep port 22 open, since I use the ssh connection via port 22 during changing the settings.

What might be the best way to configure this?

Can I stop iptables and better start firewalld and make there configurations? Or can I temporarily stop iptables, make changes and then restart iptables?

Or are there some configuration files, that I can edit?

I'm not really familiar with these configurations, but I have to do that carefully and correctly.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

For something simple like this I would use ufw. It is installed by default, but let's make sure:

`~$ which ufw` should return `\usr\bin\ufw` if ufw is installed. If ufw is *not* installed:
`~$ sudo apt-get install ufw`.

The following steps will not take affect until you enable or reload the firewall, so you will not be kicked out.

```
~$ sudo ufw default deny incoming
~$ sudo ufw default allow outgoing
~$ sudo ufw allow in 22/tcp
```

You just told the firewall to (a) not let anything in, (b) let everything out, and (c) let tcp in on port 22. To make these rules effective:

```
~ $ sudo ufw disable
~ $ sudo ufw enable
```

You will now be warned:

```
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)?
```

If you are sure you have followed these instructions carefully, answer yes. Finally, let's display the firewall status with `sudo ufw status verbose`:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Please read the ufw man page for additional information.